# can someone help me in finding the value from below output using regex

Tags: regex

Port  Link   Port-State  Dupl Speed Trunk Tag Priori MAC  Name         Type

1/1 Empty    None None None  None  No  level0 001b.ed9f.6200 test default-port

1/2 Empty None  None None  None  No  level0 001b.ed9f.6201     default-port

i want to display the value of Port(1/1) whenever the value in Name column is blank or empty.i need a regex for this.

Comment: Regex is probably not the best approach for a Fixed Column search job.

Comment: How are the values separated? Tabs, spaces? Regular expressions are, most probably, not needed.

Comment: No effort spend. SO is not a free coding service!

Comment: Thanks Peter. values are separated by tabs. Actually i need to use grako library and regex to find the value.Please suggest what can be done to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can start with something like this :

```
\d+\/\d+
```

see exemple :https://regex101.com/r/cPThs2/1